# Android studio play-services-ads:12.0.1 conflicts with appcompat-v7:27.1.0

Tags: android-studio, gradle, google-play-services, android-support-library

I am building an application with google ADS sdk and it was working fine until today I got notified to update Android studio, along with it I have also prompt to update Gradle to 4.4 and all the support library version to 27.1.0.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
```

Then I got the Gradle error saying that ***Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution***

I searched my code and there is not a single word that can match "26.1.0". I also tried to delete all the build/gradle cache but still cannot get rid of this problem. So I use **gradlew.bat -q dependencies** to find that it seems ADS library has the wrong dependency.

these two lines is very suspicious:

```
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0
```

Comparing to other dependency settings

```
+--- project :MyAdsProject
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0
|    |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|    |              \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    |    |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0
|    |    |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.0 (*)
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:12.0.1
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1
     |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0
     |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0
     |    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:12.0.1
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite-license:12.0.1
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:12.0.1
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass-license:12.0.1
     \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-license:12.0.1
```

Does any one how to get rid of this? ADS 12.0.1 is already newest release currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your app level `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    }
}
```

This will tell your gradle configuration to forcefully pick and apply `support-v4:27.1.1` everywhere it's imported!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. So, does 26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*) means it depends on 26.1.0+ but 26.1.0 just means the exact version? Is it a bug of ADS SDK?

Comment: No, it means that it found the version 26.1.0 and 27.1.0 but applied version is 27.1.0 as you have specified it for support-appcompat

Comment: I tried to add my own dependency (although not referenced in my code) and remove the resolutionStrategy.force configuration, it still works. So I guess, the reason I got the error is because that I never specify any dependency of supportv4 and mediacompat, so it use the default configuration from ADS SDK which is 26.1.0. Right?

Comment: Exactly, when we don't explicitly specify a dependency and if it finds the same internal dependency, it uses the one already found.

Comment: I had the same problem but with play-services-location 12.0.1 and this fixed it. Thanks. Personally I do think it is a sort of bug, I've never stumbled across this in the years I've been developing android and upgrading libraries every couple of months. I even have another project with the same dependencies and it works OK without having to do this fix. Something weird or different is going on since api 27 and/or AS 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I can fix this problem with add this on my depedencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

OR

add this code on your app gradle

```
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    }
}
```